# R: Webscraping a list of URLs to get a DataFrame

Tags: r, apply, rvest, sapply

I can see the correct data, but cannot put it on a Data Frame (It appears as a list of elements). I think the problem is my understanding of the apply family functions. Any hint is welcome.

Here is a similar question, but I think it is better to post mine as it contains more details:

[Webscraping content across multiple pages using rvest package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071427/webscraping-content-across-multiple-pages-using-rvest-package/43991956#43991956)

```
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)




urls <- list("http://simple.ripley.com.pe/tv-y-video/televisores/ver-todo-tv",
        "http://simple.ripley.com.pe/tv-y-video/televisores/ver-todo-tv?page=2&orderBy=seq",
        "http://simple.ripley.com.pe/tv-y-video/televisores/ver-todo-tv?page=3&orderBy=seq",
        "http://simple.ripley.com.pe/tv-y-video/televisores/ver-todo-tv?page=4&orderBy=seq")



sapply(urls, function(url){


  product_info <- function(node){
    r.precio.antes <- html_nodes(node, 'span.catalog-product-list-price') %>% html_text
    r.precio.actual <- html_nodes(node, 'span.catalog-product-offer-price') %>% html_text 
    r.producto <- html_nodes(node,"span.catalog-product-name") %>% html_text





 data.frame(
   periodo = year(Sys.Date()),
   fecha = Sys.Date(),
   ecommerce = "ripley",
   producto = r.producto,
   precio.antes = ifelse(length(r.precio.antes)==0, NA, r.precio.antes),
   precio.actual = ifelse(length(r.precio.actual)==0, NA,  r.precio.actual), 
  #tarjeta.ripley = ifelse(length(r.tarjeta)==0, NA, r.tarjeta),
   stringsAsFactors=F
 )


}



  doc <- read_html(iconv(url), to="UTF-8") %>% 
         html_nodes("div.product-description")




  do.call(rbind,lapply(doc, product_info) %>%
          bind_rows())
})
```

I'm getting a list of results, but I need a Data Frame.

```
[[1]]
              [,1]                            
periodo       "2017"                          
fecha         "2017-05-15"                    
ecommerce     "ripley"                        
producto      "LG SMART TV 43'' UHD 43UH6030 "
precio.antes  "Normal: S/ 2,199.00"           
precio.actual "Internet: S/ 1,599.00"         
              [,2]                                 
periodo       "2017"                               
fecha         "2017-05-15"                         
ecommerce     "ripley"                             
producto      "SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 40\" 40KU6000 "
precio.antes  "Normal: S/ 2,499.00"                
precio.actual "Internet: S/ 1,599.00"              
              [,3]                                 
periodo       "2017"                               
fecha         "2017-05-15"                         
ecommerce     "ripley"                             
producto      "SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 50\" 50KU6000 "
precio.antes  "Normal: S/ 3,299.00"                
precio.actual "Internet: S/ 1,799.00"
```

Edit: sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Peru.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Peru.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Peru.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Peru.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rvest_0.3.2        xml2_1.1.1         dplyr_0.5.0       
[4] purrr_0.2.2        readr_1.1.1        tidyr_0.6.1       
[7] tibble_1.3.0       ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 tidyverse_1.1.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10     compiler_3.4.0   cellranger_1.1.0
 [4] plyr_1.8.4       forcats_0.2.0    tools_3.4.0     
 [7] jsonlite_1.4     lubridate_1.6.0  gtable_0.2.0    
[10] nlme_3.1-131     lattice_0.20-35  psych_1.7.5     
[13] DBI_0.6-1        curl_2.6         parallel_3.4.0  
[16] haven_1.0.0      stringr_1.2.0    httr_1.2.1      
[19] hms_0.3          grid_3.4.0       R6_2.2.0        
[22] XML_3.98-1.7     readxl_1.0.0     foreign_0.8-67  
[25] selectr_0.3-1    reshape2_1.4.2   modelr_0.1.0    
[28] magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1     assertthat_0.2.0
[31] mnormt_1.5-5     colorspace_1.3-2 stringi_1.1.5   
[34] lazyeval_0.2.0   munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`purrr::map_df` is a version of `lapply` that coerces the result to a data.frame, which lets you do

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

urls <- list("http://simple.ripley.com.pe/tv-y-video/televisores/ver-todo-tv",
        "http://simple.ripley.com.pe/tv-y-video/televisores/ver-todo-tv?page=2&orderBy=seq",
        "http://simple.ripley.com.pe/tv-y-video/televisores/ver-todo-tv?page=3&orderBy=seq",
        "http://simple.ripley.com.pe/tv-y-video/televisores/ver-todo-tv?page=4&orderBy=seq")

h <- urls %>% map(read_html)    # scrape once, parse as necessary

h %>% map_df(~{
    r.precio.antes <- html_nodes(.x, 'span.catalog-product-list-price') %>% html_text
    r.precio.actual <- html_nodes(.x, 'span.catalog-product-offer-price') %>% html_text 

    data_frame(
        periodo = lubridate::year(Sys.Date()),
        fecha = Sys.Date(),
        ecommerce = "ripley",
        producto = html_nodes(.x, "span.catalog-product-name") %>% html_text,
        precio.antes = ifelse(length(r.precio.antes) == 0, NA, r.precio.antes),
        precio.actual = ifelse(length(r.precio.actual) == 0, NA,  r.precio.actual),
)})
#> # A tibble: 85 x 6
#>    periodo      fecha ecommerce                                 producto
#>      <dbl>     <date>     <chr>                                    <chr>
#>  1    2017 2017-05-16    ripley           LG SMART TV 43'' UHD 43UH6030 
#>  2    2017 2017-05-16    ripley       SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 40" 40KU6000 
#>  3    2017 2017-05-16    ripley       SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 50" 50KU6000 
#>  4    2017 2017-05-16    ripley SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 49" CURVO 49KU6300 
#>  5    2017 2017-05-16    ripley SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 55" CURVO 55KU6300 
#>  6    2017 2017-05-16    ripley SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 55" CURVO 55KU6500 
#>  7    2017 2017-05-16    ripley SAMSUNG SMART TV UHD 65" CURVO 65KU6500 
#>  8    2017 2017-05-16    ripley           LG SMART TV UHD 49'' 49UH6500 
#>  9    2017 2017-05-16    ripley           LG SMART TV 55'' UHD 55UH6030 
#> 10    2017 2017-05-16    ripley       LG SMART TV OLED 4K 55" OLED55B6P 
#> # ... with 75 more rows, and 2 more variables: precio.antes <chr>,
#> #   precio.actual <chr>
```

Alternatively, to fix what the list of matrices in base R, where `x` is the list resulting from the code above,

```r
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(x, t)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# or df <- as.data.frame(t(do.call(cbind, x)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi @alistaire I've tested the code provided but I'm getting this error: ` Error in eval(x$expr, data, x$env) : argument is missing, with no default`.

Comment: With the new approach or the fix for the old one at the bottom? If the former, what URL causes the issue?

Comment: It's with the new approach. I've tested every url, one by one, and the same error appears. I think the problem is in how we apply "map_df". I've posted my sessionInfo, is it similar to yours?

Comment: Not really; I'm using dev versions of a lot of packages (purrr and tibble being the only relevant ones in this case), plus I'm on macOS. Unless it's a patched bug, it shouldn't really matter, though. Does it run if you change `map_df` to `map`? If you try it a variable at a time?

Comment: It was tibble. I've donwloaded it again from github and everythings works fine. Thanks, alistaire.