# R web-scrape after a certain word in class

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape information on [this](https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A115%7D) webpage into a data frame with the following variables:

|Name|State|District|Party|ServedHouse|ServedSenate|

The 'Name' is easily scraped because it has a special class 'result-heading'. The details ('State', 'District', etc.) are harder to scrape because they all have the same class 'result-item'. The html source is reasonably structured for web scraping.

Using an altered version of the code I found in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572258/getting-text-after-a-word-r-webscraping) I tried to get R to scrape the details accurately (only record the words after a certain word), but it is not working. Probably because I do not have the right operators in the gsub() function.

```
library (dplyr)
library (xml2)
library (rvest)

Congress100 <- read_html("https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A115%7D")

name <- Congress100 %>%
  rvest::html_nodes('body') %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all("//span[contains(@class, 'result-heading')]") %>%
  rvest::html_text()

Name <- unique(name)

details <- Congress100 %>%
  rvest::html_nodes('body') %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all("//span[contains(@class, 'result-item')]") %>%
  rvest::html_text()

State <- gsub('^.*State:\ns*|\\s*</p>\n.*$', '', details)
District <- gsub('^.*District:\ns*|\\s*</p>\n.*$', '', details)
Party <- gsub('^.*Party:\ns*|\\s*</p>\n.*$', '', details)
ServedHouse <- gsub('^.*House:\ns*|\\s*</p>\n.*$', '', details)
ServedSenate <- gsub('^.*Senate:\ns*|\\s*</p>\n.*$', '', details)

df <- data.frame(Name, State, District, Party, ServedHouse, ServedSenate)
```

Can somebody spot the issue / help me with the gsub operators?

Comment: Try `Congress100  %>%  html_nodes('.expanded') %>% html_text2()` it gives you much clear data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will get you 90% of the way there. I'll highlight snippets at the bottom to guide you through my logic.

I use functions from the `stringr` and `data.table` packages in addition the `xml2` and `rvest`.

Just in case you're confused by some of the conventions I use since I don't often load up magrittr or the tdyverse.

`|>` is R's native pipe since 4.1. It does not have use of the `.` placeholder for functions that you want to use the piped data in a place other than the first arg. To do so, I use R's new anonymous functions `\(x) x+2` which is the equivalent of `function(x) x+2`

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

Congress100 <- read_html("https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A115%7D")

representatives = xml_find_all(Congress100, ".//li[@class='expanded']")

lapply(representatives, \(x) {
  rep_name = xml_find_all(x, ".//span[@class='result-heading']") |> 
    xml_text() |>
    {\(d) gsub("Representative ", "", d)}()
  
  datacols = xml_find_all(x, ".//span[@class='result-item']") |> 
    xml_text() |> 
    stringr::str_squish() |>
    stringr::str_split(pattern = ": ") |>
    lapply(\(x) {
      col = x[[1]]
      val = x[[2]]
      d = data.frame(col = val)
      names(d) = col
      d
      if (length(x) > 2) {
        col2 = "Years"
        val2 = x[[3]]
        d = cbind(d, data.frame(col2 = val2))
        names(d)[2] = col2
      }
      d
    }) |>
    {\(d) do.call(cbind, d)}()
  
  cbind(data.frame(rep_name = rep_name), datacols)
}) |>
  data.table::rbindlist(fill = TRUE)
```

Instead of grabbing each chunk in one go and stitching them back together, I made a list of each `li` element with the class `expanded`. Within each of these were the various properties you wanted to pull into a dataframe. This allows us to use `lapply` to treat each `li` as its own xml thingy. We can then `rbind` the results of each element into a dataframe once we're done.

```
representatives = xml_find_all(Congress100, ".//li[@class='expanded']")
```

From there, I pulled the representative name from the span of class result-heading and held onto that for later.
The trickier part was dealing with the spans of class "result-item" which made up our columns. We have a few issues to solve, of which I only partially completed the task.

If you step through the below code you'll see the progression:

```
representatives[1] |> 
  xml_find_all(".//span[@class='result-item']") |> 
  xml_text() |> 
  stringr::str_squish() |>
  stringr::str_split(pattern = ": ")
```

The results then get fed into a `lapply` with an anonymous function that takes the first element in the resulting character vector and sets it as the column name to the second element.

The way the table is built you might have `Served: House: 2015-2021` which our code splits into 3 elements because of the `str_split(pattern = ": ")`. To deal with this I wrote in an extra step in case the returned vector is > 2. This fails with some of the senators. I recommend finding a more dynamic solution.

The result of that chain assigned to `datacols` gets the cbind treatment along with a data.frame with the rep name. The results of all of that get passed to `data.table::rbindlist` which allows us to ignore mismatched column names  / dimension discrepancies and fill with `NA`.

Comment: Thanks, it should be easier now because thanks to the more detailed output! Had to update my R to the newest version for the code to work though.